# C Array Initialization

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I was curious about how C handles array initialization.  I have the following code in my program:

```
UChar match[] = {0xdf, 'a', 'b', '\0'};
```

Basically, this is initializing a UTF-16 string. UChar in this case is is 16 bits.

My question is: I need the trailing NULL byte at the end of the string, but it is necessary to include it in the initialization or will C automatically include that for ALL array initializations?

Comment: Depends if the array is fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a terminating '\0' (not NULL, by the way) youself - C only does that for **string literals**, not for any array.

For example -

```
char* str = "12345";
```

Will be an array with 6 chars, the sixth one being '\0'.

Same goes for -

```
char str[] = "12345";
```

It will have 6 items.

BUT -

```
char str[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' };
```

Will have exactly 5 items, without a terminating '\0'.

(in your initialization in the question you already have a '\0', so you need nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to manipulate the char array as a string then you'll need the terminating character.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you dont want to put a `\0` explicitly for a string
Suppose you know that your string contains `5` letters then create an array like this

```
char str[6]={'h','e','l','l','o'};
```

My point is that even if you half-initialize an array the rest of the values are padded with `0s`.
So for example

```
int arr[5]={1,2,3};
```

now if you do

```
printf("%d",a[3]);    or     printf("%d",a[4]);
```

both will be `0`.